# Compile time trap for using "moved from" objects

Tags: c++, c++11

You should be careful moving objects explicitly. Core guidelines recommend to avoid pointlessly use of explicit move. See [ES.56](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#es56-write-stdmove-only-when-you-need-to-explicitly-move-an-object-to-another-scope):

> Moving is done implicitly when the source is an rvalue (e.g., value in a return treatment or a function result), so don't pointlessly complicate code in those cases by writing move explicitly. Instead, write short functions that return values, and both the function's return and the caller's accepting of the return will be optimized naturally.

But sometimes you have a big function and need to use `std::move` there. I came up with a trick, which could be helpful:

```
#include <utility>

struct Moved;
#define MOVED(x) void x(Moved)

struct X {
    int x{5};
};

int foo(X x) {
    auto tmp = std::move(x);
    MOVED(x);
    return x.x;
}

int main() {
    return foo(X());
}
```

The idea is, that after move I introduce different type of symbol with the same name. There is no need for argument `Moved`, but error message looks more helpful with it:

> [x86-64 gcc 7.2 #1] error: request for member 'x' in 'x', which is of non-class type 'void(Moved)'

Is it a pessimization, or it could be helpful in practice. What do you think?

Comment: It's a better diagnostic that you would get with `struct x;`. So this could be good for declaring arguments intentionally unused, like `#define IS_UNUSED(x) (void)x;void x(Was_declared_unused)`. Funny I never thought of that.

Comment: Can you explain your question more? What are you going to do with the `x.x` if it's a different type (`void(Moved)`)?

Comment: So you're asking "How to make code that try to use moved object non-compilable and make the error message descriptive"?

Comment: I think it's better to design your types such that they end up in some valid state after being moved (if a move is indeed a move and not a copy). And then unit test the living daylights out of things. I may be just set in my ways, though...

Comment: While I think it would be good if SO supported such discussion, as it to some degree did in the early days, nowadays it's off-topic. So voted to close as subjective. Sorry.

Comment: Strange local declaration of the function `x` and trying to access the field `x` of the function, that is said by the compiler.

Comment: @user202729 The question is "I came up with a funny trick, and could that trick be helpful? Or I should not use it?".

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Correct, but unfortunate.

Comment: Thanks, I get the idea.